# Is there any solution or approximation of integral of Macdonald function multiplying with Exponential function?

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, approximation, bessel-functions

Is there any approximation or solution for this integral? The independent integral for both functions is possible while combining them I couldn’t find any solution. So, please help me to solve this. $$\int_0^\infty K_0 (2\sqrt v) \exp\left(\frac{(s+v)^2}{t}\right) \Bbb dv$$

Hint: Maybe it is possible to approximate these functions before integrating, for example, the exponential function. Is there any approximate form of $\exp{(x^2+x)}$ in the form of polynomials?

Answer (score 1):

Hoping that there is no typo, I think that the problem comes from $s$. But, even if $s=0$, the result is quite complicated since
$$\int _0^{\infty } {K_0\left(2 \sqrt{v}\right)\, e^{\frac{v^2}{t}}} \, dv=\frac 1{2 \pi}\,\,G_{1,4}^{4,1}\left(\frac{t}{16}|
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1,1
\end{array}
\right)$$ where appears the Meijer G function.

May be, an idea would to expand
$$e^{\frac{(s+v)^2}{t}}= e^{\frac{v^2}{t}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n s^n$$  where the coefficients are defined by
$$a_0=1 \qquad a_1=\frac{2v}t\qquad a_n=\frac 2{n\,t} \left(v\, a_{n-1} +a_{n-2}\right) $$to face a linear combination of integrals

$$I_n=\int _0^{\infty } {K_0\left(2 \sqrt{v}\right)\, e^{\frac{v^2}{t}}} \,v^n\, dv=\frac{2^{2 n-1}}{\pi }\,\,G_{1,4}^{4,1}\left(\frac{t}{16}|
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 \frac{n+1}{2},\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{n+2}{2},\frac{n+2}{2}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: I appreciate your valuable answer. Yes, you are right, the problem comes from $s$ which makes a quadratic equation in the exponential function. Moreover, could you please give any reference to the second equation (i.e., $e^{\frac{(s+v)^2}{t}}$.).

Comment: @AliRaza. This is just Taylor expansion built at $s=0$.